# How and where to transform a Camera Frustum onto a tilted screen?

Tags: perspective, frustum, projection-matrix

In rendering tutorials for perspective projection the assumption is that the rendering surface is perpendicular to the sight line.

As shown here:
[image]

How to accommodate for a screen that is tilted vertically and/or to one side?

This would be done in the context of screens for a vehicle window shields where the monitors are tilted forward and installed in place of the glass.

(I realize it would be better if they were perpendicular but this is beyond my control.)

Is there a way to build a custom perspective transform by defining the 4 points of the monitor in camera space and projecting to a near and far clipping plane?

Edit: to add some detail... I have the ability to modify the perspective transform that is being fed to the vertex shader that performs the transform.

I can also insert a pixel shader, but do not think a pixel shader is the correct tool.